# How to connnect two lines with different width so it looks good?

Tags: cartography, line

Simple question, how do you create a symbol with or without representation to connect two lines with different line width so it looks good?

I need to have a smooth transition between the lines, otherwise I need to create a polygon (hard job).

---

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8sJ0k30rFr2N1ZRQTRVZldRVGs

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8sJ0k30rFr2MHNPemRDVTlRbnM

ok so I tried the solution and it works, but I want it to be moore gradient like next link

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8sJ0k30rFr2NVdTTGpGbTBMT2c just for an example

we dont use outline and the round cap makes it looks like a half ball, maybe i will need to use a polygon to mask somehow

the problem is when one long straight line change symbology to much bigger width, and I want the transition to be like the third link, and when one line ends, i need it to be flat so i think i have to use polygon to mask and fill the transitions

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Sometimes round line ends look slightly better than sharp squares, but that isn't entirely satisfactory sometimes. +1 for a good question. I wonder if it is possible to have tapered line ends for a smoother transition in some software?

Comment: Can you clarify the problematic situation with a screenshot? It seems to me that symbol levels would solve this situation altogether.

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-api/samples/index.html#//01nq0000001n000000 ?

Answer (score 12):

Here I have used the Symbol Levels properties to draw the cartographic lines with casing at the bottom and fill at the top. The draw order is base 0, where 0 is the last item to be drawn. See screenshot:

[image]

You'll also want to check that line caps and joins are set to "round" in the Cartographic Line symbol properties. Do this for both layers, the casing and the fill.

[image]

This will produce correctly joined and drawn line symbols of variable widths:

[image]

See full size [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeZms.png).

Comment: I've been using silly workarounds for ages to achieve this. You're my hero.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: perfect! I will test and return if i cant achieve this :)

Comment: Excellent simple solution +1.

Answer (score 1):

If the end product will be a static map (printed etc) you could do the final touch in Adobe Illustrator where you can set the stroke width of a line on different parts of a path.

[Watch this example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9krFPi-SL_s).